# Stored Procedure providing inconsistent return values

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm working on a web form that validates data that the user uploads in the form of an Excel file. The code iterates through each row in the spreadsheet and checks against various rules, one of which is that the reference must be a unique value. I have a stored procedure that takes the `userID` and `referenceNum` as parameters:

```
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @Status AS BIT

    IF EXISTS (SELECT [TransactionMstID] 
               FROM [dbo].[tbl_TransactionMst] 
               WHERE [TransactionRef] = @DocumentNumber 
                 AND [SupplierID] = @SupplierID)
    BEGIN 
        SET @Status = 0
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @Status = 1
    END

    SELECT @Status AS [Status]
END
```

When I try different scenarios in SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS), I get the desired outputs e.g. a "0" when the reference exists and a "1" when it doesn't.

The problem arises in my C# code, it executes the stored procedure, but in my testing I get the same result irrespective of whether the data exists or not.

Here's the core of the C#:

```
    bool returnValue = true;

    if (Docnumber != null)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(GlobalSettings.connection);
        con.Open();

        SqlCommand Cmd = new SqlCommand("p_ValRefNumber", con);
        Cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DocumentNumber", Docnumber);
        Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SupplierID", SupplierID);

        Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        SqlDataReader dr = Cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (dr.Read())
        {
            bool Status = convertor.ConvertToBool(dr["Status"]);
            string test = dr["Status"].ToString();
            int testint = convertor.ConvertToInt(dr["Status"].ToString());

            if (Status == false)
            {
                //throw new System.Exception(CEObj.GetErrorDesc(101));
                returnValue = false;
            }
        }

        dr.Close();
        con.Close();
    }

    return returnValue;
}
```

No matter what the value of `docnumber` is in testing, it always shows as `True`. I've added a breakpoint so that I can check each time and then test in SSMS and I get conflicting results.

Is my logic wrong? Does Visual Studio treat the values differently? How is the result not consistent when converting it to a `string` - at the very least? It always seems to read a value of "1" in VS but varies in SSMS

Edit: here's my converter method's code:

```
public static bool ConvertToBool(object value)
{
        bool result = false;

        if (value != null)
        {
            bool.TryParse(value.ToString(), out result);
        }

        return result;
}
```

Comment: Put a break point on Docnumber. What is the value when the statement evaluates to True?

Comment: At the moment it's '12324' - a random string that doesn't exist for this user in `[tbl_TransactionMst]`

Comment: Where's the code for convertor? Maybe that is not doing what you think it is. I suggest you step through convertor.ConvertToBool in the debugger.

Comment: +1 on checking that it is converting to bool as expected. Out of interest, if you are checking one at a time, why not use an output parameter and get the value from that?

Comment: @Polyfun That's true but my `test` string shows "true" and that's not converted using that converter method. I'll update my question for completeness though

Comment: Common error.  Did it a few week ago. You are continuing through the while loop after you set returnValue to false.  So unless the last row is false you are always getting true.

Comment: The test string is irrelevant because it is not being munged by convertor.ConvertToBool, whereas Status is.

Comment: @JacobH do you mean use an output parameter in the stored procedure?

Comment: I think @jdweng is right. Daniel if you are only returning one row, then change "while (dr.Read())" to "if (dr.Read())".

Comment: @Daniel not sure if you meant me with regard to the output parameter, but if so, yeah that is what I meant. If you will only get one result there, you are already doing the checking, so just pass that back to the app as a 0 or a 1 and proceed as necessary with that info.

Comment: @Polyfun I've done that, I also added a breakpoint before my "unique reference" validation method and for some reason it appears as though the non-unique reference that I use is being 'read' as a null value now.. the string is `IS2208171229447453` and each time it iterates through a record with this value, it's showing `null`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`bool.TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.boolean.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx) isn't doing what the convertor (sic) code thinks it does.

`bool.TryParse` returns true if the value parameter equals [`bool.TrueString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.boolean.truestring(v=vs.110).aspx), which is the literal string "True".  It returns false for any other value, which means it returns false for both 0 and 1.

Also, T-SQL [bit values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/bit-transact-sql) are numbers.  The converter code isn't really necessary - just convert the return value to an Int32 and do a comparison.

```
using (var con = new SqlConnection(GlobalSettings.connection))
{
  con.Open();
  using (var cmd = new SqlCommand() { Connection = con, CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure, CommandText = "p_ValRefNumber" })
  {
    /* Assuming both parameters are integers.
       Change SqlDbType if necessary. */
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = "@DocumentNumber", SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int, Value = Docnumber });
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = "@SupplierID", SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int, Value = SupplierID });

    using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection))
    {
      return dr.Read() && (Convert.ToInt32(dr["Status"]) == 1)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Chris, can you explain that return line to me? I don't understand the syntax

Comment: The first half of the expression - `dr.Read()` - tries to read one row from the result set, and returns true if it succeeded in doing so.  The second half converts the `Status` value to an `Int32` and compares it to 1.  In plain language, the expression reads: "return if a row was successfully retrieved, and the `Status` column in that row equals 1."  Note the [&&](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-and-operator) operator will not evaluate the second half of the expression if the first half returns false (i.e. if no row was read).

Comment: Oh I see, that's far more efficient than what I was using! Your code works perfectly but it has highlighted another issue with the import from the excel file. I don't suppose you have expertise with that do you?

Comment: I might.  It would probably be best to post a new question, rather than extending this discussion.

Comment: That was a poor attempt at humour! Thank you and I'll try and use this technique going forward. Forgive my ignorance, is this a Lambda expression?

Comment: No, it's not a lambda.  See the [docs for the && operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-and-operator).